# An Asserting Appender for Log4Net?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, log4net, assert

Is there a 'standard' way to introduce assertions against Log4Net output?

E.g.

```
NUnit.Log4Net.Checkpoint()

...run some code that should not throw warnings...

NUnit.Log4Net.AssertNoErrors()
NUnit.Log4Net.AssertNoErrorsOrWarnings()
```

Or

```
NUnit.Log4Net.Checkpoint()

...code that warns user about an obsolete value...

NUnit.Log4Net.AssertOneWarnings("obsolete value used")
```

I could code an asserting appender for Log4Net but thought there must be something out there already?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no such thing (according to Google).

What we're doing is a combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159856/log4net-configuration-section-for-nunit-test-project) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252923/mock-objects-nunit-call-log-and-log4net). Basically, we've built some extension methods that enables us to do simple asserts against a [MemoryAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.MemoryAppender.html).